# Primary Key Foreign key relationship with different values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I want to create a foreign key relationship in a table but the column which i want to give relationship has an extra character. For example in primary key if it is PPL in the other table(Foreignkey) it is PPL.M. Could some one tell me how can I give relationship between these 2 columns. How to avoid the extra character.

Regards
KK

Comment: What is the problem in having that extra character still you can create `foreign key`. There is nothing like parent column and child column should have the same column name

Comment: Is the extra character in the data or in the name of the column? If it's data then you can't do it. If it's the name then you're fine. There's no rules prohibiting the linking two differently named columns as foreign keys.

Comment: Sorry I think my question was not clear. I mean the values in the rows are different. they have one extra character.

Comment: @kk236 an example of the two tables may help explain the problem.

Comment: Table A
PID
PPL,
FRM,
FRST,

Table B
PID
PPL.S,
FRM.T,
FRST.P
and so on.

I want to create primarykey and foreign key relationship between these two columns

Comment: This is a pretty clear sign that you are storing 2 pieces of information in a single intersection of your table. This violates 1NF. You need to split this into 2 columns or you are going to be fighting this design forever.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a computed column to the referenced table to trim the additional chatacter

```
alter table tablea
add coly as (substring(colx,1,5)) persisted
```

Then reference this column instead

```
alter table tableb
create constraint fk_tableb_colx 
foreign key (colx)
references tablea(coly)
```

Alternatively you could use a trigger

```
create trigger trg_tableb_fk_colx
on tableb
for insert, update
as
begin
    if exists(select 1 from inserted
              where inserted.colx not in(select substring(colx, 1, 5) from tablea))
    begin
        raiserror('violation of foreign key trg_tableb_fk_colx',16,1)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to create `Foreign Key` with **[`NOCHECK`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177463(v=sql.105).aspx)** option

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.child_table
    WITH NOCHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_childtable FOREIGN KEY (child_col) REFERENCES 
    dbo.Parent_table(Parent_col)
```